# Find the Maximum Average run of best Batsman's Position -Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Please help on this expectation,
i have a table called batsman. each batsman is playing in different position in each match.
want to find which position of the batsman is having maximum average run in what position .
Please refer the below example table and help me with SQL.

```
Name   | Position  | Runs
------------------------------
Dhoni  | 1         | 2
Kholi  | 1         | 50
Dhoni  | 2         | 23
Kholi  | 2         | 30
Dhoni  | 3         | 25
Kholi  | 3         | 12
Dhoni  | 1         | 12
Kholi  | 1         | 80
Dhoni  | 2         | 15
Kholi  | 2         | 30
Dhoni  | 3         | 60
Kholi  | 3         | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a window function for ranking:

```
select t.*
from (select name, position, avg(runs) as avg_runs,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by avg(runs) desc) as seqnum
      from t 
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same result if you dont require the avg runs by using dense_rank first:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bfcbdc/6)

```
select name,  max(position) keep (dense_rank first order by avg_run desc)
from (
select name, position, avg(runs) avg_run from table1 group by name, position)
group by name order by name;
```

Comment: wanted Avg(run ) in the result set along with name and position

Comment: Then you can go with other options such as row_number etc.